# Рефлексия в c#. Как получить исходный код метода?

Tags: c#, рефлексия, делегаты

Как получить исходный код метода? У меня есть функция которая принимает делегат Predicate и мне нужно вывести исходный код функции, которую туда передали.
Сама функция

```
public string GetSource<T>(Predicate<T> match) {
  Console.WriteLine("Source method");
}
```

Применение этой функции

```
GetSource(x => x.Name == "name");
```

Результат вызова функции в консоли: x.Name == "name"

Comment: в общем случае - никак.

Comment: Используйте не `Predicat<T>`, а `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Но все равно, в общем случае вы не получите исходный код, Только если он полностью лежит в переданной лямбде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похожие вещи делаются в C# через так называемые *деревья выражений*. Эта тема сложная, которая требует ознакомления, и её невозможно осветить в одном ответе на Stack Overflow.

Если вкратце, то для начала вы должны объявить параметр не как `Func<T, bool>`, `Action<T>` или `Predicate<T>`, а как `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` или `Expression<Predicated<T>>`.

```
public string GetSource<T>(Expression<Predicate<T>> expression)
{
    . . .
}
```

В этом случае вы не сможете просто вызывать метод, предварительно его придётся [скомпилировать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1.compile?view=netframework-4.8).

На зато вы можете *разобрать* его на составные части. В случае `x.Name == "name"` в корне дерева будет находиться объект типа [`BinaryExpression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression?view=netframework-4.8) со свойством [`NodeType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.nodetype?view=netframework-4.8) равным [`ExpressionType.Equal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressiontype?view=netframework-4.8).

Левый и правый дочерние узлы этого узла будут представлять `x.Name` и `"name"` соответственно. Проще всего пройтись в отладчике по этому дереву и посмотреть, какие объекты там встречаются.

Чтобы вывести всё это на экран, можно просто вызвать метод `expression.ToString()`. Но в сложных случаях придётся формировать строку из дерева выражения самостоятельно.

Answer (score 6):

С помощью рефлексии нельзя получить исходный код метода, так как рефлексия возвращает только ту информацию, которая есть в скомпилированной сборке. Рефлексия может дать IL-байткод метода, но не исходный код, ей неоткуда взять его. Исходный код нужно получать из каких-то других источников:

**1) Отладочные символы**

Если получение исходного кода необходимо только на машине, где ведется разработка, можно воспользоваться отладочными символами. В PDB-файлах, генерируемых компилятором, хранится информация о соответствии строк файлов исходного кода инструкциям в IL-байткоде (именно благодаря этому отладчик может при возникновении исключения может указать на конкретную строку). Определив положение начала и конца метода, считать его код из исходников - дело техники. В символах присутствует каждый метод, который физически есть в сборке, в том числе и анонимные, поэтому решение вполне применимо и для условий из лямбда-выражений.

Так как символы ссылаются на исходники по абсолютным путям, чтобы он сработал на других машинах, проект понадобится перенести на них в точности по такому же пути, как он был расположен на машине разработчика. Естественно, необязательно распространять проект целиком - главное, чтобы файл с нужным методом был доступен.

Формат PDB не документирован, однако существует несколько библиотек с открытым исходным кодом от Microsoft для работы с ним, например [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd) (в [версии 2.0](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes2.0.md) библиотеки API для чтения PDB был удален, поэтому следует использовать версию 1.Х).

**2) Декомпиляция**

Если исходники недоступны или нет символов, можно воспользоваться одним из декомпиляторов, чтобы восстановить их из байткода на лету. Например, библиотека [ICSharpCode.Decompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.Decompiler), движок декомпилятора [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), поддерживает декомпиляцию типа в синтаксическое дерево, которое можно обойти и найти нужный метод. В том числе, с помощью нее программа можно спокойно декомпилировать саму себя! Правда, чтобы корректно обрабатывать лямбды, придется отключить подстановку кода анонимных методов - в противном случае мы их в синтаксическом дереве не найдем.

Пример получения исходного кода метода двумя данными способами:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.Utilities.Pdb;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler.CSharp;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{
    class Program
    {       
        public static string GetSourceFromPdb<T>(Predicate<T> match)
        {            
            int token = match.Method.MetadataToken;

            //построим путь к файлу символов
            string module_path = match.Method.Module.FullyQualifiedName;
            string pdb_path = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(module_path),
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(module_path) + ".pdb"
                );            

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PdbReader reader = new PdbReader(pdb_path);

            using (reader)
            {
                //найдем метод в символах
                var func = reader.GetFunctionFromToken((uint)token);                

                foreach (PdbSequencePointCollection coll in func.SequencePoints)
                {
                    //считываем файл исходников
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(coll.File.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);                    

                    //найдем номера строк в файле, соответствующие началу и концу метода
                    var points_sorted = coll.Lines.
                        Where<PdbSequencePoint>((x)=> x.LineBegin <= lines.Length && x.LineEnd<=lines.Length).
                        OrderBy<PdbSequencePoint, uint>((x) => x.Offset);
                    PdbSequencePoint start = points_sorted.First();
                    PdbSequencePoint end = points_sorted.Last();   
                    
                    bool reading = false;
                    int index_start;                    
                    int index_end;
                                        
                    //считаем код метода из исходников
                    for(int i=1; i<=lines.Length;i++)
                    {
                        string line = lines[i-1];
                        index_start = 0;
                        index_end = line.Length;

                        if (!reading)
                        {
                            if (i >= start.LineBegin)
                            {
                                //первая строка
                                reading = true;
                                index_start = start.ColBegin - 1;
                                if (index_start < 0) index_start = 0;                    
                            }
                        }                        

                        if (reading)
                        {
                            if (i >= end.LineEnd)
                            {
                                //последняя строка
                                index_end = end.ColEnd - 1;
                                if (index_end > line.Length) index_end = line.Length;

                                sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(index_start, index_end - index_start));
                                break;
                            }

                            //считывание текущей строки
                            sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(index_start, index_end - index_start));
                        }  
                    }      
                }

            }
                        
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static AstNode FindNode(AstNode root,string match)
        {            
            //поиск метода в синтаксическом дереве
            var children = root.Children;

            foreach (AstNode x in children)
            {
                var s = x.ToString();
                if (s == match && x.Parent.NodeType == NodeType.Member)
                {
                    return x.Parent;
                }

                AstNode res = FindNode(x, match);
                if (res != null) return res;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static string GetSourceDecompiled<T>(Predicate<T> match)
        {        
            string module_path = match.Method.Module.FullyQualifiedName;            
                        
            var settings = new DecompilerSettings();
            settings.AnonymousMethods = false; //отключим подстановку кода анонимных методов         

            var decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler( module_path, settings );            

            //декомпилируем тип, содержащий метод
            SyntaxTree tree = decompiler.DecompileType(
                new ICSharpCode.Decompiler.TypeSystem.FullTypeName(match.Method.DeclaringType.FullName)
                );
            
            //найдем метод в синтаксическом дереве
            var children = tree.Children.ToList();
            AstNode res = null;
            foreach (var x in children)
            {
                res = FindNode(x, match.Method.Name);
                if (res != null) break;
            }

            string s = "";
            if (res != null) s = res.ToString();
            return s;
        }        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source;
            Console.WriteLine("*** Source from PDB: ***");
            source = GetSourceFromPdb<string>( (s) =>  s == "Test"  ||  s.Length==0);            
            Console.WriteLine(source);            

            Console.WriteLine("*** Decompiled source: ***");
            source = GetSourceDecompiled<string>((s) => s == "Test" || s.Length==0);            
            Console.WriteLine(source);            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }    
}
```

Результат:

```
*** Source from PDB: ***
s == "Test"  ||  s.Length==0

*** Decompiled source: ***
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__6 (string s)
{
        return s == "Test" || s.Length == 0;
}
```