# Type в C# как преобразовать в текст класса

Tags: c#

Существует ли возможность получить текст класса (исходный код) имея только переменную с типом "RuntimeType"

Comment: Что такое "текст класса"? Исходный код? Уточните задачу

Comment: да, исходный код

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1004704/240512