Как собрать технологичную трассу при сборке кода С#, где могут отображается исходники и функции?
Технологическая трасса, - это трасса по которой видно какие файлы с исходными текстами используются для какого бинарного файла, какие функции, процедуры из этих файлов используются при построении (исходя из однозначного определения состава всех файлов или функциональных объектов, используемых в ходе компиляции исходного/восстановленного кода программного обеспечения). Это не обычный лог сборки.

Что-то слишком расплывчатое. Как эта трасса в итоге должна выглядеть? Информацию о том, какой метод скомпилировался из каких строк кода по идее из символов можно взять. Вот тут есть кое-какие наработки по чтению PDB: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005282/240512
